# RewriteRule doesn't work as I expect

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want the following url:

`http://www.mydomain.com/search/string`

to go to

`http://www.mydomain.com/dir/search.php?param=string`

This is my rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule ^search/(string)$ /dir/search.php?param=$1 [NC,L]`

What's driving me crazy is that it sort of works. All the links within the result page have 'dir' within the `a` elements.  For example, I hover the mouse over a link that shows

`http://www.mydomain.com/search/myawesomescript.php`

in the status bar. The correct URL is

`http://www.mydomain.com/myawesomescript.php`

The .htaccess file is at the root.  Why does 'search' insert itself into the rewrite?  What is it that I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule is telling apache that if requests come in to search/(string) they should be handled by /dir/search.php, but it does not do anything to change the URL as being displayed.

What you're talking about would be accomplished by something like this:

```
RewriteRule .* /dir/search.php?param=$1 [NC,L]
```

Keep in mind this wold redirect **everything** to search.php, so you'd want to either modify the regex or use some `RewriteCond` rules to limit the scope.